# How to create a Vec literal from a Seq[Bool]

Tags: chisel, chiseltest

For testing inputs/outputs specified as vectors, I need to be able to programmatically create the desired Vec[Bool] for poke and expect. Seq[Bool] is a convient structure to create either directly (e.g., `Seq.tabulate(n) {i => (i%2==0).B}`) or from a UInt (e.g., `5.U(6.W).toBools`).

In a chiseltest, how can I use this Seq[Bool] for poke and expect? `Vec.Lit(Seq[Bool])` doesn't seem to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

> In a chiseltest, how can I use this Seq[Bool] for poke and expect? Vec.Lit(Seq[Bool]) doesn't seem to be supported.

I honestly have not been able to figure this out myself. We recently added convenience methods to directly `peek`/`poke`/`expect` some of the basic Chisel types with Scala values directly ([PR 480](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chiseltest/pull/480)).

This could be extended to e.g., be able to `peek`/`poke`/`expect` a `Vec[UInt]` with a `Seq[BigInt]` or a `Vec[Bool]` with a `Seq[Boolean]`. Feel free to open a PR on this. We just need *someone* to write the code.